# Why is this regex logic failing?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to build a quick script that will take a url, and check it against a list of PCREs to see if there's a match. However, it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried printing everything to make sure it's output the way I want (including the ARGV[0], passing it with single quotes appears to keep all the characters in tact). But it's still not working.

This is the script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                             

use strict;
use warnings;

if (not($ARGV[0])) {
    die "Useage: checkurl.pl \"<url>\"";
}

if ($ARGV[1]) {
    die "Too many command line arguments, try checkurl.pl \"<url>\"";
}

$_ = $ARGV[0];
print "$_\n";
my $file = "pcre.txt";

open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>) {
    if (/$line/) {
        print "Match found, the url matches the following PCRE: \n";
        print "$line\n";
    }
}
```

This is the test URL (warning, this was an actual Angler EK link, I've defanged it, just in case it's still live, so you have to fix it to properly check the PCRE)

```
hxxp://nosprivsliikeradan.pfgfoxriver-localguide2[.]com/boards/viewforum.php?f=5x827&sid=7q0as14.5i4x8
```

This is the PCRE in the pcre.txt file that matches the above URL

```
^http:\/\/(?!www|forums?)[^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.(?:[^\.\x2f]+?|[^\.]+\.[^\.]{2})\/[a-z]+\/?view(?:forum|topic)\.php\?[a-z]=(?=[^\n]{0,64}\.)[0-9a-z\.]{1,6}(?:&[a-z0-9]*=[0-9a-z\.]*){1,2}$
```

Comment: You might "defang" your regex, too...

Comment: Why do you need the start and end anchors in the regex? Also, the print statement might be better as `print "Match found, the following PCRE matches the url : \n";`

Comment: @sln: I might not need the anchors, I'm new to perl as of this week, so I know VERY little.

Comment: You really shouldn't explicitly assign to `$_`. In general it's not good if it appears in your code at all but sometimes it's unavoidable, but you should always assign it using `for` or `while` Also, your suggestion that the URL may need wrapping in quotes is wrong: if the URL contains whitespace then it's an invalid URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is actually `/^...$\n/` because you read it from a file and it contains a newline character. You need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the line before interpolating it into the match operator:

```
while (my $line = <$info>) {
    chomp($line);

    if (/$line/) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh duh... So simple, and mentioned so frequently as a "newbie perl mistake" haha. That stupid newline, first ruining my echo " " | md5sum, and now this =P That did in fact fix it, thank you.